# How to invoke client method without using RMI 

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, vnc

i am developing a client/server program in which i want to invoke a method of client program 
through server program.

this is vnc based application in which the server will be running and listening to any arbitrary port number .... the client will connect to the server using a method which has argument in the form of  ip and port number of server.
after that the server will be able to take control of the client's screen.

i want to call this method from server !!

i want to add a facility in which the client will submit a request and server will then connect to the client ..

i have heard about RMI but i want to know is there any other way available  to achieve this if not pls post some good tutorial links on RMI .

Comment: There are many other ways than RMI. What would the method do? What would be the arguments for the method and what would it return? How many different methods do you plan to have?

Comment: please see the edition in my question !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RMI` is a Java-only way for network programming or method calling but [Web Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/index.html) is language-independent. By web service you can integrate some application.

But my recommendation is using [MOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware) systems. This type of system support two approach : `Synchronous Model` and 'Asynchronous Model'. In Java `MOM` is implemented via `JMS`.(look in [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/)). `JMS` is an `API` and have several implementation such as :

- [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- [Open JMS Queue](https://mq.dev.java.net/) and etc

Answer (score 0):

better than RMI, you could make a web service and a client for it :)
http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it is desktop application ... so any comment regarding this ???